# Should changing the documented performance of a method be considered a breaking change?

Tags: performance, api, language-agnostic, documentation, backwards-compatibility

It seems a common rule in software development is that once you have deployed a public API, *especially* if you've documented that API (which—yeah, you should have), you must think long and hard before making any changes that could break backwards compatibility with that API as such changes would be *breaking changes*. In fact I'm sure many developers would argue that you just flat-out should not do it at all, regardless of how long and hard you may think about it.

Occasionally a developer will actually document the *performance* of a method. A lot of MSDN docs do this, for example, using [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_o_notation). Would changing this *also* constitute a "breaking" change? Maybe that's not a clear question; put another way: **should it be avoided?**

It seems to me that in cases where, e.g., you might have developed a superior algorithm to solve a problem, if you had previously documented that this algorithm was O(N<sup>2</sup>) you might be forgiven for *improving* your API by replacing it with this superior algorithm which is, say, O(log N). Users of your API might notice this and would, I imagine, only feel glad for improvement.

On the other hand I wonder whether it would ever be considered "excusable" to *worsen* the performance of a component of your API for other reasons—e.g., you optimize for the most common use case which results in worse performance in the general case; you optimize for memory over CPU cycles or vice versa; you eliminate an external dependency that had caused other issues, etc.

My intuition tells me that improving performance is almost certainly always OK. What about the opposite? Is it OK, assuming you update your documentation? Is it just wrong? I'm just looking for some reasonable guidelines, here.

Comment: If you method is part of a real time processing system, and you improve your performance, you may cause bugs in other parts to flourish (for example buffer overflows)

Comment: @belisarius: I thought about this too. It seems obvious at first but then you think of exceptions like this. Obviously any sort of "answer" is going to be to a certain extent context-dependent; I still feel there ought to be general guidelines, though.

Comment: @Dan Imagine you are writing a Hardware Abstraction Layer, and you improve performance. You surely know what happened to many gaming software when the CPU speeds went up by a factor of 1000

Comment: @belisarius: I must say, you are making a pretty good case for not touching performance. But that seems unsatisfying as a general answer, doesn't it? Surely in most cases it's good to improve it!

Comment: @belisarius - That was back in the '90's when some (tards) thought there was only one CPU their code would ever run on, so they used its code excecution speed for timing. When faster CPU's came out, they were forced to add a "Turbo" button to the cases so you could downgrade and tard programs still ran. That button is long gone and you can't count on customers using a specific CPU. Every OS (even RTOS's) has a timing API or two. Surely CPU speed timing now only occurrs on the barest and smallest of embedded systems. If you know one, please don't mention it. My faith in mankind is weak...

Comment: @T.E.D. You're most welcome to the unfaithful club. I am sick of finding this kind of problems in message passing systems with weak specifications.

Comment: @Dan Of course it's good to improve performance within specifications, that's the obvious answer. I think you're asking for the non-obvious part (your rep shows you are not novice!), so I tried to point out some second thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you make the performance **better** I doubt you'll get any complaints.

Otherwise, I'd say it depends. If you have access to the source code for all your clients, the upright thing to do would be to look through them all and verify that your change won't cause them any trouble.

If it is more complicated than that, and you are liable to make some use-case's performance significantly worse, then you should go talk to your clients and warn them of the change.

If you can't do that either (eg: a shrink-wrapped API of some kind), then yeah, it would probably be best to implement the change as an alternative call or something, and leave the old call alone.

Answer (score 1):

A **Breaking Change** is one that breaks ... specifications.

So, if you are dealing with a piece of software where timing (average case, worst case, variance, or whatever) or asymptotic behavior is specified, you should just avoid breaking that.  I believe this kind of specifications should be part of any project, and surely they will be there if you have real time dependencies.

You are free to improve performance, as long as functionality is respected, and I guess nobody will complain.

As to worsen performance, (again within specs and for reasonable causes) depends on the balanced impact of choices. It's a trade-off, and as such should be analyzed in a case by case basis. How could be a general rule for that if your processing time impact may vary from an unnoticed to an infuriated user?

Answer (score 1):

I note that the C++ standard requires that some functions of the STL have performance no worse than a given Big-O.

I speak from experience that if you are performing long duration batch-processes that have large data sets (2-3 hours, N~10<sup>7</sup>), an inadvertent O(N<sup>2</sup>) can be unacceptable. If an important relied upon API changed its performance from O(N) to O(N<sup>2</sup>), such a program could have its computation time so greatly extended (a 2 hours computation time could become a 4000 year computation time) that the program would be considered broken. So, I'd say that worsening Big-O performance was a breaking change.

Comment: Timing is only related to O() notation via constants. You may have a worse O(), while you get a better time for all your cases universe.

Comment: True, but in many cases the constants vary over only a few orders of magnitude, so performance for big N cases depends on the O() performance.

Answer (score 1):

Improving performance of an implementation is formally OK if you have documented it as big-O. If your new implementation is O(log n), then it is *also* O(n^2), as documented. The other way around, relaxing the limit is a breaking change from the POV of the user (since the previous property is no longer true).

So to permit better algorithms in future, don't document performance as big-Theta. In any case, it seems silly to me to *guarantee* that any operation will take at least a certain amount of time, unless you're publishing the cycle counts for CPU opcodes, interrupt frequencies from a device, or similar hardware-level stuff where exact timing is important. Just don't specify a minimum, and if a user comes to you saying, "we really need a guaranteed lower-bound time complexity on this", then write an alternative interface to the functionality:

```
int myfunc_omega_n_squared(n, args) {
    sleep(n*n); // well, actually in a loop because of spurious wakes
    return myfunc(n, args);
}
```

They can call this instead of `myfunc`, and their peculiar problem is solved ;-)

Do beware though that if you are defining an interface which others may implement (perhaps as well as your own implementation), then changing the *interface* to a stricter complexity requirement is of course a breaking change from the POV of the implementer, since their formerly-valid implementation no longer is.

That tells you whether the change is breaking in terms of what's documented. However, it's almost inconceivable that anyone would literally rely *only* on your implementation's asymptotic complexity, as opposed to its actual runtime. Absurd example, but if you change from an O(n^2) that takes an hour to process 100GB of input data, to an O(log n) that takes a week to process 100GB of data, you're probably going to get complaints from any users processing 100GB of data, regardless of the fact that you haven't actually broken your explicit interface.

What API users want is for their code to still work, so in general if you're going to make something much slower, regardless of whether it's big-O-slower or not, then there had better be a good reason. I'd want to issue a new interface rather than withdrawing and replacing the old one, if possible.